# How to split a list of number into ranges with a fixed interval with SQL?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table like this

[image]

I want to calculate the frequency ( How many times that product exists in that price range ), in intervals of "50"

So eventually it will give me a table like

[image]

Interval for range will be lets pretend a fixed 50
We don't know highest and lowest price of these each products.

So I will run the query and it will give a table as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arithmetic and aggregation:

```
select product, count(*) as frequency,
       floor(price / 50)*50 as range_start, floor(price / 50)*50 + 50 as range_end
from t 
group by product, floor(price / 50)
order by product, min(price)
```

Comment: I got his error. Any ideas? [42000][1055] Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'price' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by @Gordon

Comment: I need a solution without having to change config in database.

Comment: @Snare . . . That is weird . . . `floor(price / 50)` is a `group by` expression and the rest are just constants.  In any case, you can use `floor(min(price) / 50)` for the range_start and range_end calculations.

Comment: Can you update if possible?
I just changed that parameters in select as you said and range_start and range_end increases +1. So like (1,50), (2,52), I need 1,50,50,100